# JPA self many to many join with extra columns

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

A user can follow other users and can be followed by other users. However, that relationship has an extra parameter: the **status** of the relationship (int)
This relationship represented it in the intermediate table "Friends".

So far, I have managed to make the relationship, but without the state

```
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="Friends", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="userId")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="friendId")})
private Set<User> following = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="following", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<User> followers = new HashSet<>();
```

How could I make the relationship with that extra parameter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451894/2-foreign-keys-into-a-new-table-from-different-entities-hibernate/50455862#50455862

Comment: When you tell us where this "state" is stored in your Java classes then people can answer you, since JPA can only persist what data is in Java