# Composite Primary key in JPA with Key value structure in child table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 tables having **OneToMany** realtionship, and created entities as below

Table 1- **Network** is having primary key as networkId

Table 2- **NetworkAttributes** is having FK as networkId, but records should be considered as unique by combining "**networkId**" and "**name**" column [**name column in Attributes table not present in Network table**] and here I'm storing default value for multiple network parameter and parameters can be repeated under different network's as per below table structure in "**NetworkAttributes**",

Table Structure:-

**Network Table**:

```
 networkID | networkName | networkType

  H123M       nrouter      X
  N123Y       testR        J
```

**NetworkAttributes Table**: [key value kind of storage for default values]

```
 networkID   | name          |   value

  H123M       maxIpUser          10
  H123M       maxRouterUser      15
  N123Y       maxIpUser          23
  N123Y       maxRouterUser      25
```

**Network Entity:-**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NETWORK")
public class Network implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
private Customer customer;

@Id
@NotNull
@Column (name = "NETWORKID")
private String networkId;

@Column (name = "networkName")
private String networkName;

@Column (name = "networkType")
private String networkType;

@Column (name = "onlyActive")
private boolean onlyActive;

@OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "network")
private List<NetworkAttributes> networkAttributes;

  // Setter / Getter
```

**Network Attribute Entity:-**

```
 @Entity
 @Table (name = "NETWORK_ATTRIBUTES")
 public class NetworkAttributes implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column (name = "name")
private String name;

@Column (name = "value")
private String value;

@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn (name = "network_Id")
private Network network;

// setter / getter
```

**Problem:**
With this table structure i am not able to insert different parameters for same networks in **Network Attributes** table. giving unique constrain error. Any suggestion please

For example, you can see i am trying to insert below records, but since networkId as FK, it is not allowing to insert 2nd and 4th record.

```
  H123M       maxIpUser          10
  H123M       maxRouterUser      15
  N123Y       maxIpUser          23
  N123Y       maxRouterUser      25
```

Comment: It's not a `OneToMany` relationship, you have 2 NetworkEntity pointing to 2 NetworkAttribute records, so it's `ManyToMany`. Use a join table with attributes. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451894/2-foreign-keys-into-a-new-table-from-different-entities-hibernate/50455862#50455862

Answer (score 0):

This is a "derived identity", so `NetworkAttributes` could be mapped with an `@EmbeddedId` like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class NetworkAttributesId {
    String name;
    String networkId; // corresponds to PK type of Network
}


@Entity
@Table (name = "NETWORK_ATTRIBUTES")
public class NetworkAttributes implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    NetworkAttributesId id;

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn (name = "network_Id")
    @MapsId("networkId") // maps networkId attribute of embedded id
    private Network network;

    @Column (name = "value")
    private String value;

    ...
}
```

Derived identities are discussed (with examples) in the [JPA 2.2 spec](https://github.com/javaee/jpa-spec/blob/master/jsr338-MR/JavaPersistence.pdf) in section 2.4.1.

Comment: @Brain... Thanks  I have solved this problem using differnt way using EmbeddedId .. Inside Embeddable class i have used ManytoOne relation for Parent class. It worked

Comment: @Brain. Small difference i noticed between my implementation and yoursuggestions.. @MapsId("networkId") . Is it mandatory to use this way?

Comment: @Manu , if using an embedded `@ManyToOne` works for you, I guess it is not mandatory. : ) But, I think JPA 2.x added the `@MapsId` annotation for just this sort of situation. Does it cause any problems?