# Hibernate/JPA, How to implement relation variable?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Here is the problem that I've stumbled upon while developing a spring boot restful api application. So, I have a class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class BookModel implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String text;
    private int rank;
    private Date created;

    //THIS IS THE VARIABLE THAT I WANT TO CONFIGURE
    @Transient
    private boolean read;

}
```

In my MySQL database I have 3 tables: **books**, **users**, and **userbookrelations**.

The **userbookrelations** entry contains a book primary key (book id), a user primary key (user id), and a 'read' integer (1 means that the user has read this book, 0 means otherwise).

What would be the best way to assign this read integer from the **userbookrelations** table to the read boolean in BookModel class when user makes an api request with user id and book id? (the api call returns BookModel as JSON)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: google `@OnetoMany` `@ManyToMany` etc. Do not think in term 'assign of integer'

Comment: @JacekCz Yes, I've thought about it, but there is a problem. The user id that I want to test is not part of BookModel, so I have no idea how to use it in `@OnetoMany` or `@ManyToMany`

Comment: partial implemenattion in JPA has not sense, native queries etc ... no benefits, many disadvantages

Comment: @JacekCz so what do you think would be the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451894/2-foreign-keys-into-a-new-table-from-different-entities-hibernate/50455862#50455862

Comment: @K.Nicholas The problem is that a book can be read by over 1000 people, so the **userbookrelations** set inside UserModel can become massive. What I need to know is if only the user who sent an api request has read the book.

Comment: Many users can read a book and many books can be read by users. You have a ManyToMany relationship with a relationship attribute. Nothing you can do about that and it shouldn't be a problem. You can select book join UserBook join User where bookId = ? and userId = ? and UserBook.read = true. Pretty much straight forward database logic.