# PropertyAccessException when saving entity with @Embeddable

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, spring-data-jpa

I am following this [map a many-to-many association with extra columns tutorial](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/) but wasn't quite successfully.

So I have the following entities...

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "PEOPLE")
public class People implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "people", sequenceName = "people_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "people")
    private long peopleId;

    private String peopleName;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "people", 
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<PeopleStats> peopleStats;

    public void addStats(Stats stats) {

        if (this.peopleStats == null) {
            this.peopleStats = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        PoepleStats pStats = PoepleStats.builder().people(this).stats(stats).build();

        this.peopleStats.add(pStats);
    }
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "STATS")
public class Stats implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "stats", sequenceName = "stats_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "stats")
    private long statsId;

    private String statsName;
    private String statsDescription;

}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "PEOPLE_STATS")
public class PeopleStats implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PeopleStatsId peopleStatsId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("peopleId")
    private People people;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("statsId")
    private Stats stats;

    private long value;

}

@Data
@Embeddable
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class PeopleStatsId implements Serializable {

    // Putting @Column(name = "people_id") or not doesn't seem to have any effect
    private long peopleId;
    // Same goes for this
    private long statsId;

}
```

And then with the following unit test..

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class PeopleRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;


    @Test
    public void testSavePeople() {

        // People object created
        people.addStats(Stats.builder().statsId(new Long(1)).statsName("a").statsDescription("b").build());

        this.entityManager.persistAndFlush(people);
    }
}
```

The table generated by hibernate was as such:

```
Hibernate: create table people_stats (value bigint not null, people_people_id bigint not null, stats_stats_id bigint not null, primary key (people_people_id, stats_stats_id))
```

And this is the stacktrace..

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: Could not set field value [1](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-many-to-many-association-with-extra-columns-when-using-jpa-and-hibernate/)
>   value by reflection : [class
>   com.sample.shared.entity.PeopleStatsId.peopleId] setter of
>   com.sample.shared.entity.PeopleStatsId.peopleId   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert
>   and so on ... 63 more

I came across this [similar issue](https://www.e-learn.cn/content/wangluowenzhang/433606), with solution but not working. After trying the first solution, which is creating a `new PeopleStatsId` object for the `@EmbeddedId`, it throws me the same error.

Anyone can guide me along? Thanks.

Update 1: I have uploaded a POC on [github](https://github.com/bwgjoseph/embeddable-id).

**Update 2**:

```
public void addStats(Stats stats) {

        if (this.peopleStats == null) {
            this.peopleStats = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        PeopleStats pStats = PeopleStats.builder().peopleStatsId(new PeopleStatsId()).people(this).stats(stats).build();

        this.peopleStats.add(pStats);
    }
```

It is now throwing detached entity error.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity
>   passed to persist: com.sample.Stats   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:807)
>     ... 68 more

**Update 3**:

I have changed `CascadeType.ALL` to `MERGE` and it seem to solve the problem, but I'm not so sure why though. I even removed the portion in update 2 about `.peopleStatsId(new PeopleStatsId())` and it works as well. Now I'm even more puzzled.

In People Class:

```
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "people", 
            cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, 
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<PeopleStats> peopleStats;

    public void addStats(Stats stats) {

        if (this.peopleStats == null) {
            this.peopleStats = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        PeopleStats pStats = PeopleStats.builder().people(this).stats(stats).build();

        this.peopleStats.add(pStats);
    }
```

Comment: You need to set people and stats in peoplestats.

Comment: Please elaborate. I'm not too sure what you mean by that. Thanks.

Comment: You need to set the People and Stats fields in the PeopleStats entity.

Comment: I still do not understand. Do you mean to have a setter method or ? Could you show with code example? I have uploaded a POC in github.

Comment: There is plenty in SO about this sort of thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451894/2-foreign-keys-into-a-new-table-from-different-entities-hibernate/50455862#50455862

Comment: I have added the new PeopleStatsId() in my addStats, and throwing me a detached entity error now. When I added the new PeopleStatsId() in PeopleStats class, it doesn't seem to does the same. Hence I'm not aware of it. Have updated the original post.

Comment: `stats(stats)` doesn't make sense. A detached entity means you're out of the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instatiate peopleStatsId in your PeopleStats class. So change line:

```
@EmbeddedId
private PeopleStatsId peopleStatsId;
```

to this:

```
@EmbeddedId
private PeopleStatsId peopleStatsId = new PeopleStatsId();
```

Hibernate is trying to set fields of PeopleStatsId but the instance is equal to null so the NullPointerException is thrown.

Comment: I have tried that, it gives the same error. I have mentioned that in the last part of my original post. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

So after help from `@K.Nicholas` and research, I think I have managed to resolve the issue and learned new things from it.

`@K.Nicholas` was right about settings the fields for People and Stats but it wasn't quite clear to me initially. Anyway, it got to me later me.

Basically, all other classes stays pretty much the same except for `People` class.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Builder
@Table(name = "PEOPLE")
public class People implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "people", sequenceName = "people_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "people")
    private long peopleId;

    private String peopleName;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "people", 
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
            orphanRemoval = true
    )
    private List<PeopleStats> peopleStats;

    // Maintain the state of objects association
    public void addStats(Stats stats) {

        if (this.peopleStats == null) {
            this.peopleStats = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        // Important to ensure that a new instance of PeopleStatsId is being passed into the field
        // otherwise, PropertyAccessException will be encountered
        PeopleStats pStats = PeopleStats.builder()
                                .people(this)
                                .stats(stats)
                                .peopleStatsId(new PeopleStatsId(this.getPeopleId(), stats.getStatsId()))
                                .build();

        this.peopleStats.add(pStats);
    }

}
```

Take note of the comment in `addStats` method where I need to pass in a new instance of `PeopleStatsId` object to initialize the `PeopleStatsId` object which should have been done so in the first place except that it wasn't. Lesson learnt.

I also mentioned that I met with the issue of detached entity previously. It was because I was trying to set in the Stats id field when it wasn't required.

According to [Hibernate Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html),

> **detached**
>
> the entity has an associated identifier, but is no longer associated with a persistence context (usually because the persistence
>   context was closed or the instance was evicted from the context)

In my post, I was trying to set in Stats to People, then persist it.

```
@Test
    public void testSavePeople() {

        // People object created
        people.addStats(Stats.builder().statsId(new Long(1)).statsName("a").statsDescription("b").build());

        this.entityManager.persistAndFlush(people);
    }
```

The `.statsId(new Long(1))` was the problem, because it was considered as a detached entity since there was an id. `CascadeType.MERGE` would work in this case is because I think due to the saveOrUpdate feature? Anyway, without setting statsId, `CascadeType.ALL` would work just fine.

An sample of the unit test (working):

```
@Test
    public void testSavePeopleWithOneStats() {

        // Creates People entity
        People people = this.generatePeopleWithoutId();
        // Retrieve existing stats from StatsRepository
        Stats stats = this.statsRepository.findById(new Long(1)).get();
        // Add Stats to People
        people.addStats(stats);
        // Persist and retrieve
        People p = this.entityManager.persistFlushFind(people);

        assertThat(p.getPeopleStats().size()).isEqualTo(1);
    }
```

I had a `data-h2.sql` script which loaded in Stats data upon starting of unit test, that's why I can retrieve it from `statsRepository`.

I have also updated my [poc in github](https://github.com/bwgjoseph/embeddable-id).

Hope this helps with whoever comes next.